# Template for cheat sheet

Tags: templates, plain-tex, documentation

I have been working with LaTeX for a couple of years but I don't know anything about pure TeX.

I find this LaTeX [cheat sheet](http://www.stdout.org/~winston/latex/) useful to remember some commands. So I'd like to have a LaTeX template for writing down my commands on different subjects with such cheat sheet model. Do you know where I can find such template or how to create a new one from scratch with TeX?

Comment: You already have the LaTeX source for the cheatsheet in the link you provide. But looking for `TeX cheatsheet` in Google I've found [this one from Joseph H. Silverman](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/) Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't see the LaTex source in my own link. I always used only the pdf version and I found this link only now for writing this question. Thanks anyway for the other link.

Comment: If you write an answer I would accept it. Otherwise this post will remain open.

Comment: You might be interested in this SO question: [How to make cheat sheets in Latex?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1911516/562769).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the [LaTeX cheat sheet](http://www.stdout.org/~winston/latex/) web page you can find both pdf and LaTeX source:

[image]

A reference sheet for plain TeX (also pdf and source) can be found in [Joseph H. Silverman's](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/) web page.

Comment: Many thanks for the link to the plain TeX cheat sheet, as this is probably the best resource around for LaTeX writers now trying to learn plain TeX, such as myself. Learning TeX in >2020 yields quizzical looks and responses: ``are you {\it sure\/} your advisor meant {\it plain\/} TeX?''

Answer (score 2):

I've once made a cheat sheet with ConTeXt/metafun (looong time ago) which was quite fun. I've uploaded it to https://gist.github.com/1203210

See the image below.

[image: emacs cheat sheet sample]

Comment: I like your solution but I think is quite simple and dirty for what I am looking for. I'll stick it with the first answer. Thanks anyway maybe I can learn something from your code.