# How can get rid of margins and minimize white space to fully use a page in LaTeX?

Tags: spacing, margins, columns, landscape

I want to create a formulary in LaTeX. I can use it at the exam and it has do be at maximum a page recto-verso. I don't want margins (only the strict necessary for printing). I also want to minimize the withe space (between text and formulas, ...). I want to use the page in landscape and subdivide it in 4-5 columns. It is possible to create a similar thing?

It has to look like this handwritten formulary (sorry for the bad quality):
[image: handwritten page]

Comment: You can use [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for margins/landscape, [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) for columns setup.

Comment: have you seen [these questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=cheat+sheet), in particular, [how-to-scale-entire-document-including-maths-symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33164/how-to-scale-entire-document-including-maths-symbols)? I'd be tempted to call this a duplicate... let us know

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27832/template-for-cheat-sheet

Comment: You can get some ideas looking at the `.tex` file of [latexcheat](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/latexcheat/latexcheat).

Comment: @cmhughes I want something little different. I changed the image so you can see. I don't want something typographically good. I want to maximize the use of space: no space between formulas and text, no space between text and columns, very thin font, ... Basically I want to reproduce the image in LaTeX.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. See above.

Comment: You should also have a look at the [savetrees](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/savetrees) package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another option, using the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package to change the page layout, the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package to get a four-column document and a redefinition of `\normalsize` to decrease the font size and the values for `\abovedisplyskip`, `\belowdisplayskip`, and their "short" variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3pt,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}%just to generate text for the example

% redefinition of \normalsize to use \footnotesize and decrease the values for
% \abovedisplyskip, \belowdisplayskip, and the "short" variants
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
  \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@viiipt{9.5}%
   \abovedisplayskip 1\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
   \belowdisplayskip 1\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

% multicol parameters
\setlength\premulticols{1pt}
\setlength\postmulticols{1pt}
\setlength\multicolsep{1pt}
\setlength\columnsep{2pt}
\raggedright

\newcommand\TestText{% just to generate text for the example
\lipsum[4]
\begin{gather*}
E = mc^2.
\end{gather*}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{align*}
a &= b \\
&= c \\
&= d.
\end{align*}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\TestText\TestText\TestText\TestText\TestText%
\TestText\TestText\TestText\TestText\TestText
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do something similar once, but then was told that only handwritten text was allowed, so I never got past a crude template. It squeezes 36 `lipsum` paragraphs on 2 pages, where you usually would have 14, so tell me if it suits your needs:

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=5mm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[condensed,math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}

\setlength{\columnsep}{2mm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.70}\normalsize

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\raggedcolumns

\begin{multicols*}{5}
\section{Mechanics}
\lipsum[1-5]
\[ \int_0^1f(x)\ dx \]
\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Thermodynamics}
\lipsum[11-15]
\[ \int_0^1f(x)\ dx \]
\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Quantummagic}
\lipsum[21-25]
\[ \int_0^1f(x)\ dx \]
\lipsum[26-30]
\section{Relativity}
\lipsum[31-34]
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Both answers are very good but I accepted the other because a I better understand the code.