Illegal control sequence name for \newcommand
I'm trying to make a post on mathsstackexchange, and I wanted to make the following shortcut:
\newcommand{\R2}{\mathbb{R}^2}

and received the error "Illegal control sequence name for \newcommand".  The error goes away if I remove the number 2, and make it \Rt.  I'd rather not.
I've done similar shortcuts in LaTeX successfully, though that was a while ago.  Is this a problem specifically with Stackexchange?  Is there a way around it?

Welcome to TeX.SE. Syntax for valid control sequences is a backslash character followed by (a) one or more Latin-alphabet uppercase and/or lowercase letters (texnically, characters with category 11, "letter") or (b) a single non-letter character, e.g., \$ or \{. "R2" is a combination of letter and nonletter characters and thus violates the syntax requirement. In contrast, "Rt" consists of letters only, making \Rt a syntactically valid control sequence name.

Ah, thank you.  So no (reasonable) way around it?  Was this true outside of SE?   I'm sure I've used this before.

I'm extra motivated to have shortcut because I have ^2 autocomplete to ² for texting, which is convenient when doing that, but when I'm trying to type it to latex it also converts, which is not what I want.  So I'm having to retype every superscript a few times and say "No, don't make it an actual superscript!"

You can use numbers in a control sequence, but you'll have to change the way you use/reference it. That is, there's no convenient user interface for such macros. As an example: \expandafter\newcommand\csname R2\endcsname{\mathbb{R}^2} and then you can use \csname R2\endcsname as opposed to \R2. Alternatively, \newcommand{\usevar}[1]{\csname #1\endcsname} which would allow you to use \usevar{R2}.

A macro \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs} -> <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs might be of interest.

why can't you use \Rt? and why are you declaring the command in maths mode? you asked whether this was 'true outside SE?' could you clarify? the limitation has nothing to do with SE. indeed, it doesn't apply here at all since no SE site has the ability to compile TeX code. on this particular SE site, you can write \R2 as you wish and will never get an error. some other sites in SE do render markup, so perhaps that wouldn't work on those sites, but it still has nothing to do with TeX as that's not what they use.

I can use /Rt, it's just not intuitive to write or read and doesn't look like the output.  It looks like that's what I'll probably do though.  It's not the end of the world, but I'm also looking for a long term solution.   By "outside of SE" I mean in LaTeX when compiling pdfs.  I bring this up because I thought I remembered using it.  I placed it in maths mode because otherwise it doesn't register as a command (on mathsstackexchange).

You are correct, mathsstackechange doesn't use TX, it uses MathJax, but the commands are the same.  This thread https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91585/tex-commands-and-latex-commands-whats-the-difference-good-introductory-manual says that that's because MathJax is written using LaTeX.

Thanks Werner and Ulrich.  I think I more or less follow the ways to get around it.  I don't think I'll implement them in ym stack exchange post.  Perhaps I will revisit these methods when it comes time again to write up longer documents.

Have you considered defining \newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}} in the preamble and typing \R, \R^2, \R^n, etc in the body of the document (in math mode, obviously)? For sure, lots and lots of people like to define \newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}, \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}, \newcommand\Q{\mathbb{Q}}, etc.

MathJaX doesn't use LaTeX it is just modelled after it, so uses a similar syntax. And MathJaX is generally off topic here. Otherwise what @Mico said, use \R^2.

There are many ways to tackle this "problem" in TeX. You could even change the superscript character from ^ to something else, but this is a bad idea. I really think the best approach here is to turn off your "autocomplete" replacement. Maybe you can turn it off just for .tex files? Or maybe just switch to a different replacement shortcut and leave the ^ alone?

The problem is, afaik, I'd have to turn it off system-wide, for All devices, including my phone, were I use it all the time, more often than I post on SE fora.

why would you have to turn it off for all devices?

Because I do not know of another way to do it.  I initialised it on my phone, and it transferred to my computer.  It's possible that somehow I can keep two separate autocomplete lists, or even better, app-specific ones.  This is not something that I have looked into.

If you need to typeset \mathbb{R}^2 sufficiently frequently to contemplate creating a shortcut macro for this expression, I will assume that you also need to typeset \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^n, etc. at least occasionally.
Instead of creating shortcut macros for each and every one of these expressions, I suggest you define
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

in the preamble and input
\R \R^2 \R^3 \R^n 

in the body of the document (in math mode, naturally). I trust that typing \R^2 is not much more burdensome than typing \R2 is.

If you simply can't get by without being able to input \R2 directly, I suggest you train your editor software to automatically replace \R2 with \mathbb{R}^2 as you input stuff into your document.
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amssymb}    % for '\mathbb' macro
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
$\R \ \R^2 \ \R^3 \ \R^n$
\end{document}


Thanks for your input.  This is true that this is easier.  However, I specifically am trying to avoid typing the superscript because, as I said in the comments, my autocomplete keeps trying to actually put a superscript in.

@FurrierTransform - I suppose that you could also define \newcommand{\R}[1][2]{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}, so that the default argument of \R would be 2. With this definition of the macro, you'd write \R to generate \mathbb{R}^2; to generate \mathbb{R}^3 and \mathbb{R}^n, you'd have to input \R[3] and \R[n], respectively. This method may be best if you need to generate \mathbb{R}^2 most of the time, and \mathbb{R}^3 and \mathbb{R}^n only occasionally.

@FurrierTransform Probably a silly idea, but if your computer changes ^2 to ², you could also tell TeX to accept another char as superscript marker. So, for example with \catcode`\"=7, you could write $\mathbb{R}"2$ in your document (of course, you should be careful not to catcodify a character that you also need to use in other contexts).

@Mico AH!  That is what I should have done and might do next time.  The question is posted, but in that particular context, I'm talking about the complex plane, so I didn't have too much need for R rather than R².

@JasperHabicht Thanks.  This is also a good solution for my case actually.  I'm not so worried about clashes, because it's for individual posts on mathsSE.  Similarly, I'm hesitant to write lots of header for that reason.

@FurrierTransform But don’t they use MathJaX on Math.SE? I doubt that MathJaX has a concept of catcodes.

I'll try it.  To make sure I understand what's happening and I'm inputting this correctly, the \catcode command changes the category code Mico mentioned of. character.  We are trying to change " to mean superscript.  We use the ``` to type the actual symbol which we want to change, instead of its character code, and the \ to escape ".  Is superscript just a category code?  I'm thinking if I wanted to change " to mean the letter A, then I'd first change the catcode to 11 for "letter", but then I still need to specify which letter.  Is the same true for superscript?

The post preview doesn't render $ \catcode\"=7 $` correctly, so I'm guessing it doesn't work.

@FurrierTransform that's because it doesn't use TeX ;). and that's why MathJax is off-topic here ...

@FurrierTransform - Unless you really, really know what you're doing (do you?), I would advise against making changes to the default category codes of various characters. While you could change the category code of the " character from 12 ("other") to 7 ("superscript initiator"), do be aware that " gets used in lots of places. Do you really want to find out what happens if you change the catcode of " to 7?

@cfr Yes. I understand.  I didn't know that when I posted, because I have always just used my "LaTeX" to typeset my posts.  So I asked a question about LaTeX.  I now understand that a LaTeX answer may not help my original problem.  It is, however, nonetheless enlightening, and, as I do use LaTeX to do very similar things, perhaps useful.

@Mico I empathise with this sentiment.  I would not do it when typing up a PDFfor exactly the reason you suggest.  However, since this question was about making a post on a SE forum, in a small, closed environment, with limited scope, I'm less scared of doing something horrendous.  Particularly since I would use superscripts on mathsSE far more than quotes.  But I understand your point and agree.

@FurrierTransform - As cfr has already told you, the StackExchange sites use MathJax, not TeX, as the underlying engine to render math material. (MathJax is disabled on TeX.SE., of course.) MathJax doesn't know squat about catcodes.

Yes, as I said in my last reply, I understand that.  Thank you for your help.
